# Change input position after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to save the position of the input element using localStorage.
I saved the position of my input element and after page reload I can access it but it's always in default position after page refresh. (Value true/false)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" value="false" id="c1">
  <label for="c1"><span></span></label>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
const chk = document.getElementById('c1');
var storedPosition = localStorage.getItem('saved');
console.log("Saved input value: " + storedPosition);

chk.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if(chk.value === "false"){
    chk.value = "true";
    console.log(chk.value);
  }else{
    chk.value = "false";
    console.log(chk.value);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('saved',chk.value);
});
```

To be clear I am creating a chrome extension (options-page).

**EDIT:**

```
const chk = document.getElementById('c1');
var storedPosition = localStorage.getItem('saved');
console.log("Saved input value: " + storedPosition);
chk.value = storedPosition; //edited set different value

chk.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if(chk.value === "false"){
    chk.value = "true";
    console.log(chk.value);
  }else{
    chk.value = "false";
    console.log(chk.value);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('saved',chk.value);
});
```

Comment: by position, do you mean the position of the cursor of the actual value of the input field?

Comment: Note that checkboxes have a `checked` property by default, so you don't have to track this yourself.

Comment: by position I mean when I turn on my input element shows "ON" and after page reload it stays "ON".

Comment: You've taken no action when the page loads. If you want the input to have a different value when the page loads you must set the value (`chk.value = storedPosition`).

Comment: I edited the code but the result is still the same.

Comment: **chk.value = storedPosition;** does not change the visual `checked` state. Like Wais wrote you need to set the property [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox). The `value` property merely sets the value which gets posted. Also keep in mind that `checked` is a boolean property. `chk.checked = storedPosition === 'true'` would change is visually.

Comment: @Lain thank you for clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

Primarily you should use [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) instead of `value`. While `checked` is the *(visual)* checked state of the input, `value` is the value which gets posted.

Also you can make it more simple by storing the value in  `localStorage` as number "0" or "1" which can easily be converted back to a boolean.

```
window.onload = function(){
    const chk = document.getElementById('c1');

    //REM: Changed "saved" to the id of the element
    //REM: Also in the change listener to make it more dynamic
    const storedPosition = localStorage.getItem(chk.id);
    console.log("Saved input value: " + !!+storedPosition);

    //REM: Use the property "checked" and not the "value"
    //REM: Be aware that the value is a string with either null, "0" or "1"
    //REM: which can be converted to a number (0 or 1)
    chk.checked = +storedPosition;

    //REM: Change event
    chk.addEventListener("change", () => {
        //REM: Use the property "checked" and not the "value"
        //REM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox
        //REM: Store the boolean as a number to spare conversions
        localStorage.setItem(this.id, +this.checked);

        //REM: You can omit the rest, unless you want to post it
        /*
        if(chk.value === "false"){
            chk.value = "true";
            console.log(chk.value);
        }else{
            chk.value = "false";
            console.log(chk.value);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('saved',chk.value);
        */
    })
}
```